# Increase the disk size of docker (Error: Insufficient space)

Tags: docker, docker-machine, bazel, tensorflow-serving, docker-image

I am running docker on a windows machine and I have a Tensorflow Serving docker image. On checking the disk space of my image, the following details are displayed:

[image: image description here]

On building, TensorFlow serving using the command "bazel build tensorflow_serving/...", the build gets terminated and an error is displayed stating "Insufficient space". I need to increase the disk size so that there is sufficient space for the build. However, I am unable to figure a way in which I could do that. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using VirtualBox, which is the default driver for Docker Machine, you can use the command-line tool `vboxmanage` to manage the VM.

[modifymedium](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi) lets you resize a disk - e.g. to 100GB:

```
vboxmanage modifymedium c:\my\vm\location\docker-vm.vdi --resize 100000
```

Comment: Where can I locate the docker-vm.vdi file? My machines are at the following path "C:\Users\KBT2\.docker\machine\machines\default". On running the above command "vboxmanage modifymedium C:\Users\KBT2\.docker\machine\machines\default\docker-vm.vdi --resize 100000" the following error is displayed "Could not find file for the medium"

Comment: It may be a `.vmdk` rather than a `.vdi` - the [default size](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/virtualbox/#/environment-variables-and-default-values) is 20GB, so you should have a file that size in the default machine location.

Comment: I have a vmdk file called disk in the above mentioned path. On running the command `"vboxmanage modifymedium c:\my\vm\location\docker-vm.vdi --resize 100000"` the following error is displayed: `Resize medium operation for this format is not implemented yet!`

Comment: Ah, in that case it's more awkward. You can use [vboxmanage clonemedium](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-clonevdi) to copy the disk file, writing the output in VDI format. Then resize the VDI file, then clone it back to VMDK and delete the original. Or if you're not worried about existing contents, delete the VM and use `docker-machine` to create a new one with `--virtualbox-disk-size` option.

Comment: I cloned the disk file and created a VDI format of it and executed the command. However, I am still facing the same problem.

Comment: The problem is resolved. The issue was with the disk size. I was resizing the disk to a size lesser than  the actually allocated size. On entering a size greater than the current size, the command worked. However, I am still facing the problem that I initially did. On running a docker image for TensorFlow Serving the disk space available for it is just 18GB. Can you help me figure out why is the disk space not 200GB (which I allocated to it?)

Comment: @Vasanti Reading i found that "[...]Note however that this only changes the drive capacity. You will typically next need to use a partition management tool inside the guest to adjust the main partition to fill the drive." So inside the docker you need do that. Link where i found that https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-clonemedium